# NESTJS Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "...". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator

Tags: docker, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

i am trying to build nestjs api using graphql, postresql and docker when i try to build up my api i get this error
`/app/node_modules/@nestjs/graphql/dist/schema-builder/factories/output-type.factory.js:19 stocks-api-api-1               |                 throw new cannot_determine_output_type_error_1.CannotDetermineOutputTypeError(hostType); stocks-api-api-1               |                       ^ stocks-api-api-1               | Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "createStock". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.`

Here is what my code looks like

create-stock.dto:

```
import { Field, InputType, ObjectType } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

@InputType()
export class CreateStockDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Field()
    ticker: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Field()
    price : number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Field()
    timestamp : Date;
}
```

stocks.entity.ts:

```
import { Field, ObjectType, ID } from "type-graphql";
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Stock extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Field(type => ID)
    id: string;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    ticker: string;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    price: number;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    timestamp: Date;
}
```

stocks.resolver.ts

```
import { Args, Mutation, Resolver, Query, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Stock } from '../entities/stocks.entity';
import { CreateStockDto } from '../dtos/create-stock.dto';
import { StocksService } from '../stocks.service';

@Resolver()
@ObjectType()
export class StocksResolver {

    constructor(private stocksService: StocksService) {}

    @Query(() => [Stock]) 
    async getStocks(): Promise<Stock[]> {
        return this.stocksService.getStocks();
    }

    @Mutation(() => Stock)
    async createStock(
        @Args('stock') createTaskDto: CreateStockDto
    ): Promise<Stock> {
        return this.stocksService.createStock(createTaskDto);
    }


}
```

stock.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StocksService } from './stocks.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { StocksRepository } from './stocks.repository';
import { StocksResolver } from './resolvers/stocks.resolver';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([StocksRepository])],
  providers: [StocksResolver,StocksService],
})
export class StocksModule {}
stocks.repository.ts:
import { Repository } from "typeorm";
import { Stock } from "./entities/stocks.entity";
import { CreateStockDto } from "./dtos/create-stock.dto";
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class StocksRepository {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Stock)
        private repository: Repository<Stock>,
    ) {}

    async getStocks(): Promise<Stock[]> {
        const query = this.repository.createQueryBuilder('stock');
        const stocks = await query.getMany();
        return stocks;
    }

    async createStock({ ticker, price, timestamp }: CreateStockDto): Promise<Stock> {
        const stock = this.repository.create({
            ticker,
            price,
            timestamp
        });

        try {
            await this.repository.save(stock);
            return stock;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
    }
}
```

stocks.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { StocksRepository } from './stocks.repository';
import { CreateStockDto } from './dtos/create-stock.dto';
import { Stock } from './entities/stocks.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class StocksService {
    constructor(
    @InjectRepository(StocksRepository)
    private stocksRepository: StocksRepository,
    ) {}

    async getStocks(): Promise<Stock[]> {
    return await this.stocksRepository.getStocks();
    }

    async createStock(createStockDto: CreateStockDto): Promise<Stock> {
    return await this.stocksRepository.createStock(createStockDto);
    }
}
```

i think i am sitting on this problem like 4th hour and can't resolve it for my eye all those files looks like they are decorated properly. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The output type error is for the "createStock"

Comment: I do not think the `@ObjectType()` decorator on `StocksResolver` is necessary/desirable.  Although that might not be the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be a mismatch on types. Looks like you are returning Stock, instead try to create a stock-dto.output.ts-> StockDtoOutput so you can control exactly what you are returning. Let's say your DB is converting price from number to Float, the resolver might expect Int while the entity is returning Float, therefore it's not clear what you want to return. Also check your schema.gql so you can verify the type of the fields that you are returning.